# Facebook wall post link to the application

Tags: android, facebook, post

When you post on facebook's wall via the android SDK, there is a little link at the bottom of each post. For example here you can see "via deezer" : [image]

When I post on facebook's wall, the post has my application's icon, and a message "via MY_APPLICATION" but this message is not a link. When I post the following data, there is the link :

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", message);
```

But when I post more data, there is no link !

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", message);
params.putString("name", name);
params.putString("caption", caption);
params.putString("description", description);
params.putString("picture", image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();

params.putString("to", String.valueOf(friendId));
params.putString("caption", " ");
params.putString("description", getString(R.string.post_description));
params.putString("picture", "IMAGE URL");
params.putString("name", "YOUR NAME");
params.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");



Utility.mFacebook.dialog(YOURACTIVITY.this, "stream.publish", params,new PostDialogListener());
```

It will Surly post the appropriate data to the facebook wall.